# JavaScript edit CSS style position value

Tags: position, css-position

**EDIT: Basically working code**

My goal is to have my logo above the navigation bar of my website but when I scroll down the logo should disappear and the nav bar should stay fixed at the top.

Example Website which has this: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

I implemented a go back up button according to the tutorial [here](http://html-tuts.com/back-to-top-button-jquery/) in order to see if js works and it does.
Here is my code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46myas39/2/). I have modified the js from the go back up example but it doesn't work.

In this code snippet I get an error that I don't know but the same js works in the "go back up button" example.

```js
var amountScrolled = 100;
var navbar = document.getElementById('navbar-eff');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled ) {
        navbar.style.position = "fixed";
    } else {
        navbar.style.position = "relative";
    }
});
```

```css
ul.navbar {
        position: relative
        z-index:99999;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        font-size: 100%;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul.navbar li {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

ul.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25em 0.25em;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo">
  <h1>
  my logo
  </h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar" id="navbar-eff" style="">
      <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li> <a href="hello_world">Hello World</a></li>
      <li> <a href="about_me">About Me</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
<header>
<p> Lorem <br>ipsum <br>dolor<br> sit<br> amet<br>, consectetur<br> adipiscing<br> elit,<br> sed<br> do<br> eiusmod <br>tempor<br> incididunt<br> ut<br> labore<br> et<br> dolore<br> magna<br> aliqua<br>. Ut<br> enim<br> ad<br> minim<br> veniam,<br> quis <br>nostrud<br> exercitation<br> ullamco<br> laboris<br> nisi<br> ut<br> aliquip<br> ex<br> ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
  
</header>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't work because you need to include jQuery explicitly, just like in the fiddle. But what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Oh ok I found my error after re-re-rechecking my code I had a typo in the path of the js file. So this is basically working code, thank you @MrLister for asking me for the exact problem. I checked everything again and now it's working